# Problemas com adb do android

Tags: ionic

Bom dia pessoal
Sou usuário de Mac e estou tentando rodar meu app ionic no meu dispositivo android, através do comando...

> ionic run android --device
>   .. porém a seguinte mensagem aparece no terminal.
>
> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code null
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Alguém sabe que problema é esse?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que adicionar a variável de ambiente. Siga os passos:

- [Abra as variáveis de ambiente do windows](https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/path.xml)
- Na variavel ANDROID_HOME configure o caminho onde está instalado o adb, normalmente em `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

[Tutorial mais completo](https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/) (em inglês).

Comment: Não estou em ambiente Windows e sim num Mac.
E já tenho minhas variáveis de ambiente declaradas.

Comment: Recomendo informar na pergunta esta informação. Não conheço MAC, mas tenta rodar `cordova run android`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.